# How can I filter a file based on my input file?

Tags: database, emeditor

I have list of phone number (25million)
I want to use that list as input file.
Lets say that I have  email phone database and I want to only extract phone number that available in input file(25 million)
How can I do that in em editor? Or in any large file?

Comment: What is the format of phone numbers? Is the phone number at a certain columns of every line or any other specific location that can lead to the location of phone numbers (for instance, after "phone:", etc.)? Please write a small sample.

Comment: Usa phone number without country code
both file phone number are in same row first line.input file has only phone number. The file i want to filter has phone and email. I want extract same phone number that input file has.

Comment: Do you want to extract only the matched phone numbers or the whole lines containing the matched phone numbers?

Comment: İ would like to learn both

Comment: My problem is my input file has 25million phone number and i tryna do batch extract but it didn't work out.

Comment: editor is not really the best tool for something like this.  grep or other command-line search/edit tool makes more sense.

Comment: Well I don't have much experience about grep  so can you teach me how?

Comment: How many lines is the email-phone database file?

Comment: İt doesn't matter actually. İ can make it split 1 million row and compare each split with 25million input file

Comment: İf you are asking minimum to ,i can go with 1 million email-phone

Comment: Anyone will tell me how can I do that with em editor? Or something similar

Comment: I am working on it; please wait for a while. I need to take some time to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a 25 million phone number list (`file A`) and a phone-email database file (`file B`).

**To extract all matched lines or matched strings (updated)**

1. Please make sure EmEditor is up-to-date including beta versions (v21.5.910 or later).
2. Optionally, presort `file A` to make filtering faster. To do this, open `file A` with EmEditor, click the **Sort A to Z** button on the **Sort** toolbar to sort, and save the file as a different file name if you prefer (`file A2`).
3. Open `file B` with EmEditor.
4. Drag and drop `file A2` or `file A` from **Explorer** to the **Filter** box on the **Filter** toolbar. (Alternatively, click **Advanced Filter** button on the **Filter** toolbar. Click `▼` on the right side of the **Add** button, select **Add a Linked File**. Select `file A2` or `file A`.)
5. Make sure the **Match Case** option is set.
6. Click **Filter** button. Wait for the filtering finish. This might take several minutes. Then click **Close** button.

[image: Advanced Filter]

7. Click **Extract All** drop-down button on the **Filter** toolbar, then select **Extract All Lines** if you would like to retrieve all matched lines, or select **Extract All Matches** to retrieve all matched strings.

[image: Filter toolbar]

The filter and extract processes take only several seconds to finish.

Comment: What about emails? Are the duplicate phone number lines will be available with the duplicates

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this comment question.

Comment: İnput file has only phones, my second file has email and phone. İ want compare and extract same phone number to another file with the emails

Comment: That's **To extract all matched lines**.

Comment: Yes but i need emails to come with as well.

Comment: If `file B` contains emails, you will get emails by **To extract all matched lines**. Did you try already?

Comment: İt's working but only extract 2 matched lines.if there is 3-4 matched lines,it doesn't extract

Comment: I am not sure if I understand `2 matched lines.if there is 3-4 matched lines`. In which file? Please write more details.

Comment: For example My emails-phone file has 1 matched phone with 5 different email . İt only extract 2 records

Comment: Are you using **To extract all matched lines**? Are you absolutely sure that these 5 email lines in `file B` contain one identical phone number (with an identical format) and different emails? If so, please [contact me](https://www.emeditor.com/support/#contact), and I will instruct you how to send me sample files.

Comment: The problem is, in some cases file d is not small enough and it would takes forever extract all matched lines

Comment: How many lines is `file D` at maximum?

Comment: 100k lines , my file b is 5-10 million row.

Comment: Please update EmEditor to v21.5.906, which significantly improved the speed of Advanced Filter.

Comment: I've updated the **To extract all matched lines (Updated)** part of my answer.